# "came through for me" or "has come through for me"?

Tags: tense

To everyone that has come through for me, thank you.

To everyone that came through for me, thank you.

I am of the opinion that the 'has' in the first sentence is redundant and that the second sentence is better. Secondly, does the first sentence have a different meaning?

Comment: Compare *[I'd like to] thank everyone who helped* and *...everyone who **has** helped* in [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thank+everyone+who+helped%2Cthank+everyone+who+has+helped&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthank%20everyone%20who%20helped%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthank%20everyone%20who%20has%20helped%3B%2Cc0). Arguably the latter (less common) form implies extending the category further towards people who helped *a long time ago*, but in practice this is probably usually an irrelevant/contextually obvious nuance anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think that they are both correct. The difference between then is the difference between present perfect and past.

> To everyone that has come through for me, thank you

**Present perfect**. "Has" is not redundant at all because this form implies always to have + participle.  This form is used - according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present/present-perfect-simple-i-have-worked) - *to refer to events in the past but which connect to the present*. People that has come through for you during a period of time until today.

> To everyone that came through for me, thank you

**Past**. It references an specific moment in the past. People that came through for you just one time, one special day, only during 2017, ... but that may not help or support you today.